# Installing command line tool with pgAdmin4

Tags: postgresql, windows

I have `pgAdmin4` and the latest version of PostgreSQL installed on my machine. When I tried to insert large amount of data using INSERT statements contained in a `.sql` file of size 40 MB, 50MB and above, the app crashed. Hence, I am wondering if dumping heavy data using those sql files via command line is a good idea? If yes, then from where can I install that command line utility in `pgAdmin4` ?

Comment: if You have installed PostgreSQL - You are already have all. psql - then select database and use command -  \i file.sql

Comment: @a_vlad Could you tell me from where I could access psql? Either from pgAdmin4 or by going into `Program Files/PostgreSQL/10/` folder and going again into one of the folder listed there? There are many like bin,data, doc etc

Comment: CMD windows, if PostgreSQL in PATH - just type psql -u postgres -p , if not - first cd to Program Files/PostgreSQL/10/bin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Firstly**, I have no idea about [pgAdmin4](https://www.pgadmin.org/download/)

**Secondly**, It would take a lot of time when executing a large SQL file. Please consider using [pg_dump](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/10/static/app-pgdump.html) (*custom format*) & [pg_restore](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/10/static/app-pgrestore.html) to enhance your performance.

> Output a **custom-format** archive suitable for input into pg_restore.
>   Together with the directory output format, this is the most flexible
>   output format in that it allows manual selection and reordering of
>   archived items during restore. This format is also **compressed** by
>   default.

**For example:**

```
-----#### Exporting large table with custom format
pg_dump -h your_host -p 5432 -U user_name  --format custom --no-password   --encoding UTF8  --no-security-labels --no-tablespaces --table=your_schema_name.your_table_name --verbose --file your_file_name.backup --schema your_schema_name your_database_name  

-----#### Importing large table with custom format
pg_restore -h your_host -p 5432 -U user_name --dbname=your_database_name --role=user_name  --format custom --no-tablespaces --schema=your_schema_name --verbose your_file_name.backup
```

Comment: Thanks. I believe the above commands needs to be executed in the command line. Could you tell me how can I access the plsql so that I could run the command line to run above commands? Also, I am little bit unclear as to what the `pg_dump` and `pg_restore` will do to the 50 MB `.sql` file. Could you please elaborate? TIA